# How to limit SQL to one record based on ID

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a table called bids, that have multiple rows.

these all have unique IDs however they have a listingID as well, so everytime it inserts it inserts a new row but with that listingID.

I'm trying to only return one unique result for the ListingID as appose to all the bids in the table , I tried SELECT DISTINCT and group by, but both didn't seem to work.

At the moment this is printing all the records from the table 'bids'

I would like to only print the last record for the listingID column.

```
$bids = $this->db->query("SELECT bidID,listingID, listing_title, bid_date, username,amount, starting_, sold, vintage, bottles, size, cases, sold_date, bid_type,
FORMAT(`bin`, 0) AS `bin`,
(CASE
WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bids WHERE bid_listing = listingID )
THEN
(SELECT FORMAT(amount,0) FROM bids WHERE bid_listing = listingID  ORDER BY bidID DESC LIMIT 1)
ELSE
FORMAT(`starting_`, 0)
END
) AS `starting`
FROM (`bids`)
JOIN listings ON listingID = bid_listing
JOIN users ON list_uID = userID
WHERE bidder_ID = $userID
ORDER BY bidID DESC");
```

Comment: use `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query?

Comment: this isn't a bad question but if you simply paste your question title into google you'd have your answer.  voting down for lack of research effort

Comment: I did research and I tried. I put Limit 1, but then it only shows 1record, so for example if I have 6 different records (with unique listingID) it only shows 1 record in total, not all 6.

Comment: Maybe my question was not detailed enough, I've edited it.

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. What is the input? If there is more than one row matching what is supposed to be output? What do you mean by "last"--according to what ordering? If you want the last by listing id (asc? desc?) why are you ordering on bid id? You give a query, but it's wrong. You order & limit in a subquery in the select clause, but that is applied (if the case applies) per multiple rows coming from the outer from etc, so that subquery can be applied to many rows. Why do you expect us to know what you want? (Rhetorical.) Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try this sql. I used b1.* because I don't know what fields you're trying to return.

```
$bids = $this->db->query("select b1.* from bids b1
        left join bids b2 on (b1.listingID  = b2.listingID and b1.bidID < b2.bidID
        where b2.bidID is null");
```